# Use bind_rows to convert list of vectors to dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list of vectors that I would like to convert into a dataframe.

**Code**

```
a <- list( c(1,2,3,4), 
           c(1,2,3,4), 
           c(4,5,6,3), 
           c(6,3,2,6))
```

With help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662457/convert-list-of-vectors-to-data-frame), I was able to do so in the following manner:

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% 
   reduce(rbind) %>% 
   as.data.frame()

> a %>% reduce(rbind) %>% as.data.frame()
      V1 V2 V3 V4
out    1  2  3  4
elt    1  2  3  4
elt.1  4  5  6  3
elt.2  6  3  2  6
```

I would like to use `purrr`'s `bind_rows()` function (`a %>% bind_rows`), as it seems more convenient. However, this generates an error:

> Error: Argument 1 must have names.

**Questions**

1. What is happening here?
2. How can I prevent it from happening ;) ?

Comment: Maybe base: `do.call(rbind, a)`

Comment: `bind_rows()` is originally a `dplyr` function and is designed to bind together `data.frame`s or `tibble`s. Since `data.frame` columns have names, `bind_rows` expect the input to be named, thats why you get an error. `rbind` is less strict here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
map_dfr(a, ~ set_names(.x, paste0("V", seq_along(.x))))

     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     4
2     1     2     3     4
3     4     5     6     3
4     6     3     2     6
```

Comment: Getting same error? (Maybe version issue: R version 3.6.2; tidyverse_1.3.0)

Comment: @zx8754 yes, with `bind_rows(a)` I get the same error as the OP.

Comment: There is no need to use `purrr`'s `map()`: `a %>% set_names(., c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")) %>% bind_rows`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan `set_names()` is actually from `purrr` :) In addition, your solution is binding the opposite way as desired.

Comment: @tmfmnk It works very well! Just for my understanding: what does the `~` actually do?

Comment: @tmfmnk you are right, without `map` `set_names()` is naming the list elements and not the vectors, which is why my approach transposes the matrix. `set_names()` however, is originally from `rlang`.